# Use the Kubernetes REST API without kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

You can simply interact with K8s using its REST API. For example to get pods:

```
curl http://IPADDR/api/v1/pods
```

However I can't find any example of authentication based only on curl or REST. All the examples show the usage of `kubectl` as proxy or as a way to get credentials.

If I already own the `.kubeconfig`, and nothing else, is there any way to send the HTTP requests directly (e.g. with a token) without using `kubectl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kubeconfig` file you download when you first install the cluster includes a client certificate and key. For example:

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ...
    server: https://api.cluster1.ocp.virt:6443
  name: cluster1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster1
    user: admin
  name: admin
current-context: admin
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ...
    client-key-data: ...
```

If you extract the `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` to
files, you can use them to authenticate with curl. To extract the
data:

```
$ yq  -r '.users[0].user."client-certificate-data"'  kubeconfig | base64 -d > cert
$ yq  -r '.users[0].user."client-key-data"'  kubeconfig | base64 -d >
key
```

And then using `curl`:

```
$ curl -k --cert cert --key key \
  'https://api.cluster1.ocp.virt:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500'
{
  "kind": "PodList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "22022"
  },
  "items": []
```

---

Alternately, if your `.kubeconfig` has tokens in it, like this:

```
[...]
users:
- name: your_username/api-clustername-domain:6443
  user:
    token: sha256~...
```

Then you can use that token as a bearer token:

```
$ curl -k https://api.mycluster.mydomain:6443/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer sha256~...'
```

...but note that those tokens typically expire after some time, while the certificates should work indefinitely (unless they are revoked somehow).

Comment: Great, your solution worked in pure Ruby... However I cannot verify the K8s server certificate in the client (I need to use `-k`, or VERIFY_NONE, as you suggest). Does the K8s API use self-signed certificates? Is there any way to get the correct CA root certificate for K8s?

Comment: The CA certificate provided in the `kubeconfig` should be able to verify the API certificate (I mean, that's the whole point to this answer). When you say, "in the client", are you talking specifically about `kubectl` or about some other client that you're working with? By default the API uses certificate signed by the Kubernetes CA, but I believe it's possible to replace that with a certificate signed by a globally trusted CA like letsencrypt.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have found the solution and now I can use `VERIFY_PEER`: there's a `certificate-authority-data` in the `kubeconfig` that is the CA root certificate (used by K8s for its HTTPS API). So you don't need to use the insecure `-k` option if you use that CA root certificate.